# using java jdbc downloading blob(audio) from mysql.Things goes well, but I cant play the audio

Tags: java, mysql, audio, blob

As the title described, when I download the blob(audio) file from MySQL, things goes well and I get the file, but I can't play the audio immediately, unless I terminate the progress.

I guess the audio file is being occupated by the program, if so how can I solve this problem without terminate the program. thx!

Here the code:

```
public void downloadAudio(int documentid,String pathname) {
    String sql = "SELECT storage FROM chatroom_tool WHERE documentid=?";
    ResultSet rSet = null;
    try {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setInt(1, documentid);
        rSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

        File file = new File(pathname);
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        System.out.println("writing to file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        while (rSet.next()) {
            InputStream inputStream = rSet.getBinaryStream("storage");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("downLoad success +++++");

    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the picture when I open the audio without terminating the program.
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iraIj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inputStream.read does not have to fill the array with data completely, it returns the number of bytes it read. You must use the return value when you write the data to the output stream.

```
while ((bytes =inputStream.read(buffer)) >0)
    output.write(buffer, bytes);
```

Also you have to close the output stream - Windows does not let other apps open the file as long as your program has it open

Comment: I guess I understand something. Could you please tell me how to fix the code correctly. Thanks.@Joni